# python selenium search for exact text in web table

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am struggling to find syntax when trying to locate exact text in web table with Selenium and Python.

Table xpath is:

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="someId"]/table[2]')

There are 4 columns and unknown number of rows. I am interested only in **First** column. Example xpath of 3 rows:

```
//*[@id="sameValue"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/input
//*[@id="sameValue"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/input
//*[@id="sameValue"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/input
```

Basically, I have radio buttons in first column and I want to click on the row in First column that has **MY VALUE**. I don`t know if it will be 4th or 26th row. I know it is the First column. Some additional details:

```
<td class="class value" width="70">
<input type="radio" name="FileName" value="some Value">
</td>

<td class="class value" width="70">
<input type="radio" name="FileName" value="some Value">
</td>

<td class="class value" width="70">
<input type="radio" name="FileName" value="some Value">
</td>

<td class="class value" width="70">
<input type="radio" name="FileName" value="MY VALUE">
</td>
```

And one more thing the name I am looking for comes as variable. I guess syntax will be some F -string, so please give me hints about that too, if you can.

Thank you for your time, knowledge and effort. They are much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the input element with value attribute as  `value="MY VALUE"` use the either of the following `xpath`.

```
//*[@id='sameValue']/table[2]/tbody//tr//td[1]/input[@value='MY VALUE']
```

Or

```
//input[@value='MY VALUE']
```

In python you could use the python `format()` function.

```
strvar="MY VALUE"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sameValue']/table[2]/tbody//tr//td[1]/input[@value='{}']".format(strvar)).click()
```

Comment: Thank you KunduK. Your help is much appreciated. This was exactly  what I was struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Try xpath locating by value text:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='MY VALUE']")
```